# Update 100+ record in cakephp 2x

Tags: cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

i am new in cakephp2x . i want to update my table which has two field like userid and point. This table content atleast 500 record now in my function i have to update atleast 100+ record ie i have to change the users point according to the userid.
  thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Cake ORM. Please read this page

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html

my guess is that you'll need to use the updateAll() method, something like:

```
$this->User->updateAll(
    array('point' => 'something')
);
```

Hope this helps